# Single MySQL query to return different categorized averages

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database which contains a table with 3 columns: survey, type and response. Each survey can have multiple types and each type can have multiple responses. Response is an integer.

```
|--------|-------|----------|
| survey | type  | response |
|--------|-------|----------|
| Food   | Men   |    4     |
|--------|-------|----------|
| Food   | Men   |    5     |   
|--------|-------|----------|
| Food   | Women |    1     |
|--------|-------|----------|
| Food   | Women |    3     | 
|--------|-------|----------|
| Drink  | Old   |    3     |
|--------|-------|----------|
| Drink  | Old   |    5     |   
|--------|-------|----------|
| Drink  | Young |    1     |
|--------|-------|----------|
```

Is it possible, in a single SQL query, to return the average response for all responses from the same surveys AND for all responses from the same type?

Using the following SQL with `GROUP BY` returns averages for each type

```
`SELECT survey, type, AVG(response) FROM 'test' GROUP BY survey, type`
```

but is there a way to modify the query to also return survey averages (which are a combination of types) to output something like below?

```
|--------|-------|---------------|
| survey | type  | AVG(response) |
|--------|-------|---------------|
| Food   | Men   |      4.5      |
|--------|-------|---------------|
| Food   | Women |       2       |
|--------|-------|---------------|
| Food   | ----- |      3.25     | 
|--------|-------|---------------|
| Drink  | Old   |       4       |
|--------|-------|---------------|
| Drink  | Young |       1       |   
|--------|-------|---------------|
| Drink  | ----- |      2.5      |
|--------|-------|---------------|
```

Currently I have to use a loop to input new survey and type values to retrieve both of these average responses however if this can be achieved without a loop, in a single query, it would be more efficient.

I'm using a very simplified table in this example to illustrate the question :)

Comment: Simple solution: UNION ALL a query there you GROUP BY survey only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also give a try using WITH ROLLUP option

```
create table t(survey varchar(50),type varchar(50), response int);

insert into t values('Food','Men',4);
insert into t values('Food','Men',5);
insert into t values('Food','Women',1);
insert into t values('Food','Women',3);
insert into t values('Drink','Old',3);
insert into t values('Drink','Old',5);
insert into t values('Drink','Young',1);


select survey,type,avg(response)
  from t
group by survey,type with rollup;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `OVER` clause with `PARTITION BY` for this

```
SELECT survey, 
       type, 
       AVG(response) AS AVGTYPE,
       AVG(response) OVER(PARTITION BY survey) AS AVGSURVEY 
FROM test 
GROUP BY survey, type
```